# Offscreen FBO on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on an iPhone 4, iOS 6.0.1. I'm creating an offscreen FBO with a different size than the main FBO. I use the following code to do that, where cxFBO and cyFBO are twice the size of the main FBO:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, cxFBO, cyFBO);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBufferID);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);

glGenTextures(1, &_fboTextureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fboTextureID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, cxFBO, cyFBO, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fboTextureID, 0);
```

I'm then drawing to it after calling `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBufferID)`. I don't want to post the entire drawing routine with shaders. I think I'm not doing anything special, but if you think it matters, I will post a short example. The problem is that only one quarter of the texture is filled with vertices, the other 3 quarters are the color set by `glClearColor()`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm especially a bit confused about the formats, i.e. `GL_RGBA`. Should I rather use `GL_RGBA_OES`? Everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to call glViewPort(). Kind of obvious if you think about it ;-)